# getPhotoUrl() or profile pic with google login

Tags: android, authentication, google-api, google-oauth

I'm using Google Api to integrate **google login** in my Android App.
It works very well, at the moment, and I'm able to retrieve the user name and the email, but **I'm not able to retrieve the user profile pic**.

When I try to execute  `account.getPhotoUrl();`, I always get "`null`".
I set the profile picture in my google account, so I'm pretty sure I should get something different from "`null`".
Obviously, photo_url is declared as Uri.

As I read on [Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInAccount), I added `.requestProfile()` to retrieve information about the user profile, but I always get `null` for the profile photo.

How can I solve the problem?

```
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .requestProfile()
                .build();

        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);

                                 ....

    private void handleSignInResult(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {
            try {
                GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);
                googleName = account.getDisplayName();
                goofleEmail = account.getEmail();
                photo_url = account.getPhotoUrl();
                Log.w(TAG, "test url" + photo_url);

                mainPresenter.dataSocialAPI(googleName, goofleEmail, userType);
                signOut();
            } catch (ApiException e) {
                Log.w(TAG, "signInResult:failed code=" + e.getStatusCode());
            }
        }
```

Comment: I found out that I can use this URL: https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/USER_ID?fields=image&key=API_KEY but the result is a JSON content. How can I directly retrieve the URL from the JSON response?

Comment: I still get "null" from getPhotoUrl(); I searched a lot on google, but I didn't find any suitable explaination to my problem.

Comment: of course, the google account I'm using for the test is associated to the Google+ system, this is the link: https://plus.google.com/u/0/103592606781375438677

Answer (score 0):

Might be late but i found this solution with Picasso:

Add this in your app/build.grade under dependencies

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

In your Activity:

```
Uri personPhoto = acct.getPhotoUrl();
photo = root.findViewById(R.id.accPhoto);
Picasso.with(this).load(personPhoto).into(photo);
```